# Keeping rows that meet conditions that depend on other columns using coldate function in R

Tags: r

I have a data set in R called BvD7. It is a data frame that includes columns with headings "ID" (individual ID), "Birth_Date", "OlderBrothers" (number of older brothers), and "OlderBrotherDate" (date at which the number of older brothers of the individual was recorded). Each row is an event occurring on a particular individual.

I am interested in the number of brothers an individual has at birth, so I would like to only keep records of OlderBrothers where the OlderBrother_Date is as close to the Birth_Date as possible.

I tried the following:

```
which(BvD7$Birth_Date-coldate) == min(BvD7$OlderBrothers_Date-coldate)
```

But I recieved the message:

```
Error in which(BvD7$Birth_Date - coldate) : object 'coldate' not found
```

Does anyone know what I should do to derive a column that only displays number of older brothers at the nearest possible date to Birth Date?

Comment: It's not really clear what the `coldate` variable is here. Can you give a bit more info please? Also, what do you mean by "as close as possible"? Do you mean e.g. within 30 days?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I say "as close as possible", because ideally I would like to know the number of older brothers an individual had on their birth date. However, for most individuals, the number of brothers they have is not recorded on their date of birth, but at a point in time where their number of brothers changed...I would like each individual in my data set to have only one value for "older brothers", and this value should be the one recorded at the "OlderBrothers_date" equal to or as close as possible to "Birth_Date".

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a few questions in my comment but in the meantime, here is a reproducible example that adds a column to show the number of older brothers an observation has if the number of older brothers is counted at a date after the observation's birth date, and NA otherwise. You might be able to modify this code to get closer to what you are actually after.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(12345)

id <- seq(1:20)
birth_date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2010/12/31'), by="day"), 20)
older_brothers <- sample(x = 1:4, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
older_brothers_counting_date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2009/01/01'), as.Date('2011/12/31'), by="day"), 20)

df <- data.frame(id, birth_date, older_brothers, older_brothers_counting_date)

df %>% 
    mutate(older_brothers_at_birth_date = ifelse(older_brothers_counting_date > birth_date, older_brothers, NA))

# the line above returns this:

   id birth_date older_brothers older_brothers_counting_date older_brothers_at_birth_date
1   1 2010-05-22              1                   2010-09-27                            1
2   2 2010-02-20              4                   2010-07-26                            4
3   3 2010-07-27              4                   2011-03-11                            4
4   4 2010-08-06              4                   2009-02-05                           NA
5   5 2010-08-08              2                   2011-08-29                            2
6   6 2010-06-01              4                   2009-06-15                           NA
7   7 2010-11-10              3                   2011-06-20                            3
8   8 2010-04-03              1                   2010-12-24                            1
9   9 2010-03-16              2                   2010-11-08                            2
10 10 2010-12-18              1                   2010-07-24                           NA
11 11 2010-08-04              4                   2010-03-27                           NA
12 12 2010-09-15              4                   2011-12-24                            4
13 13 2010-03-27              2                   2009-01-13                           NA
14 14 2010-12-23              3                   2011-01-05                            3
15 15 2010-02-07              4                   2010-03-09                            4
16 16 2010-04-13              4                   2010-08-09                            4
17 17 2010-09-23              2                   2009-02-25                           NA
18 18 2010-02-09              4                   2009-12-29                           NA
19 19 2010-10-21              2                   2010-11-06                            2
20 20 2010-10-13              4                   2011-08-05                            4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have a go at using this